# Docker bash: syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "then")

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I try to run bash scripts in Docker, buit I keep getting this error:

> ./scripts/proto-generator.sh: line 13: syntax error: unexpected "(" (expecting "then")

Here's my proto-generator.sh file:

```bash
function printGreen() {
    printf "\e[0;32m$1\e[0;m\n"
}

function printRed() {
    printf "\e[0;31m$1\e[0;m\n"
}

service=$1
outDir=./src/services/$service/models
protoDir=./protos/"${service}Service"/*.proto

if ! [[ "$service" =~ ^(file|user)$ ]]; then
    printRed "Incorrect service: $service"
    exit 1
fi

./node_modules/.bin/proto-loader-gen-types \
    --longs=String \
    --enums=String \
    --defaults \
    --oneofs \
    --grpcLib=@grpc/grpc-js \
    --outDir=$outDir \
    $protoDir

printGreen "GRPC codes generated: ${outDir}"
```

How can I fix the syntax error?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: I don't think that you are running this by bash. From the bash-viewpoint, the script looks syntactically correct.

Answer (score 5):

I would have loved to ask that question as a comment, but I'm not allowed to, yet. Anyway, after having had a quick test, I assume your docker image is Alpine Linux-based. The standard Alpine Linux docker images do not come with a bash as you might be expecting but with an [ash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ash) and ash does not have a `[[`-built in command, i.e. you should be sticking to the standard `[` aka `test` command or get goind completely without it. And, sadly enough, `test` does not have the ability to handle regular expressions.

That said and again assuming that you do not want to bloat the Alpine image with a complete bash, `grep` comes to the rescue. A solution for your case would be (lines 13, ff.)

```
if ! echo $service | grep -qE "^(file|user)$" ; then
    printRed "Incorrect service: $service"
    exit 1
fi
```

---

**explanation**

Make the `if` directly test the return code from `grep` using your pattern. `grep` returns non-zero if there was no match, 0 otherwise. `-q` suppresses output of the match, `-E` switches to extended regular expression, as needed for the `|`.

Comment: This is a better answer than the one I provided, 
I decided to go for the "bash" solution because of the title of the answer ;)

Comment: You can also use `grep -q` instead of the replacement with sed: `if echo "$service" | grep -q -e 'file' -e 'user'; then`. You can `-F` for fixed strings, use `-w` for whole words, or `-x` for line regex. Meaning that `grep -Fxq -e file -e user` will return a successful status code if a line is equal "file" or "user". And in OP's case they need to invert the status code from grep: `if ! grep ...; then`

Comment: Thanks! Tbh using grep would be even smarter. I'm gonna see if I can edit my answer.

Comment: Exactly @AndreasLouv .

Comment: A few nitpicks, remember to quote parameter expansions: `echo $service` -> `echo "$service"` to avoid the parameter undergoing wordsplitting and pathname expansion. It could be worth printing the error to stderr, by redirecting the output to `>&2 printf "..." "$1"` It "wrong" to expand the parameter inside the format string, `printf "%s" "$1"` should be used instead. One could consider checking if the output is a terminal (possible `test -t 1` or `test -t 2` would be sufficient), and if not, then avoid printing the escape sequences for colors.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a

```
#!/bin/bash
```

at the top of the script

I think you are executing it in /bin/sh,
and sh doesn't support bash regex.
Or you are using an outdated version of bash, regex in bash where introduced recently.

Comment: `=~` was added in bash 3.0, over 10 years ago. Even MacOS runs bash 3.2.